# Pass a list attribute lightning to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx

I have an attribute in lightning component and it has a value like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="samListObj" type="Object"/>

[{"created":"","description":"","docId":"","docType":"Claims Documents","docTypeList":[],"fileName":""}, 
{"created":"","description":"","docId":"","docType":"Client Identification Documents","docTypeList":[],"fileName":""}, 
{"created":"","description":"","docId":"","docType":"Execution Only","docTypeList":[],"fileName":""}, 
{"created":"","description":"","docId":"","docType":"Invoice","docTypeList":[],"fileName":""},
{"created":"","description":"","docId":"","docType":"Ongoing Advice Agreements","docTypeList":[],"fileName":""}]
```

Now I am passing the value into my Apex Class Controller from my lightning controller, like this:

```
var action = component.get('c.controllerMethod');
action.setParams({
 'samValue':component.get('v.samListObj')
});
action.setCallBack(this,function(result){
  if(result.getState()){
   console.log('SUCCESS');
  }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Now in Apex code I have a wrapper class with the same field from my attribute like this:

```
public class DocumentWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String docId = ''; 
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String docType = ''; 
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String fileName = '';
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String created = '';  
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String description = '';   
    @AuraEnabled 
    public List<String> docTypeList = new List<String>();      
}
```

So for my method that calls to my lightning js controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateAPDesciptionCFCheck(List<DocumentWrapper> samValue){
   System.debug(samValue);
}
```

Now I tried to debug the value from my lightning component but it returns empty in every fields:

```
DocumentWrapper:[created=, description=, docId=, docType=, docTypeList=(), fileName=], 
DocumentWrapper:[created=, description=, docId=, docType=, docTypeList=(), fileName=], 
DocumentWrapper:[created=, description=, docId=, docType=, docTypeList=(), fileName=], 
DocumentWrapper:[created=, description=, docId=, docType=, docTypeList=(), fileName=], 
DocumentWrapper:[created=, description=, docId=, docType=, docTypeList=(), fileName=]
```

For the docType field it should have a value base from the value of the attribute in my component. But I couldn't pull the data.

Any help please?

**NOTE**: I updated the actual display in my debug log.

Comment: Could you try sending serialized list and deserialize it on server side? And I believe 'DocumentWrapper' is defined as an outer class?

Comment: My wrapper is inside in my Controller Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some quick testing, and there are 2 options to resolve the issue:

1. Irrespective of whether your wrapper class is outer or inner, add `{get; set;}` to `@AuraEnabled` properties for data binding to work.

   ```
   public class DocumentWrapper {
       @AuraEnabled 
       public String docId { get; set; } 
       @AuraEnabled 
       public String docType { get; set; }
       @AuraEnabled 
       public String fileName { get; set; }
       @AuraEnabled 
       public String created { get; set; }
       @AuraEnabled 
       public String description { get; set; }
       @AuraEnabled 
       public List<String> docTypeList { get; set; }     
   }
   ```

   Quoting from documentation- [Passing Data to an Apex Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_pass_data.htm):

   > Each property in the Apex class must have an @AuraEnabled annotation, as well as a getter and setter.
2. Another safer option which I prefer to use is to send a serialized JSON string to server side and deserialize that in apex method.

   From client side controller, you can serialize the attribute to string with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

   ```
   action.setParams({ 'samValue' : JSON.stringify(component.get('v.samListObj')) });
   ```

   Then in apex controller method, [deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) it as:

   ```
   public with sharing class Class_267042 {
       @AuraEnabled
       public static void updateAPDesciptionCFCheck(String samValueString){
           List<DocumentWrapper> samValue = (List<DocumentWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(samValueString, List<DocumentWrapper>.class);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: How do  I send a serialized JSON string into server side? That's what I am looking for.

Comment: @LeorahSumarong added more details in the answer

Comment: I tried using the 1st option, But I am getting an error, Do I need to convert the value from my controller like JSON.stringify?

Comment: I got this error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void serialize(String, System.Type) from the type System.JSON", 
I tried to used the second option.

Comment: is it serialize or deserialize?

Comment: That should be deserialize, made typo in my psuedo code

Comment: It's ok, There's no error though, but there is no dispayed in my debug log.

Comment: Thank you very much, I manage to get the values.